# Importing A Database Into MySQL Has A Cluster System

Tags: mysql, percona

I have a big issue. I want to import a database to mysql-server in a Centos 7 system. But there is a cluster structure on the servers. I set **pxc_strict_mode=ENFORCING** in **wsrep.conf** file. I have not to change this config.
Here is the error code: **ERROR 1105 (HY000) at line 50: Percona-XtraDB-Cluster prohibits use of LOCK TABLE/FLUSH TABLE  WITH READ LOCK/FOR EXPORT with pxc_strict_mode = ENFORCING**

The command that I tried is **mysql -u test_user -p < my_db.sql**

How can I import this database to mysql-server? Please help me.

Comment: remove those commands from the backup file?

Comment: Hi RiggsFolly.  Which commands do you mean? May you specify them?

Comment: The commands the error message tells you about.

Comment: Thank you so much mustaccio and RiggsFolly. It worked. Thank you again.